# Чтение файла в буфер

Tags: node.js, файлы

Собственно читаю ~500 мбайтный файл и по частям и укладываю всё это дело в буфер.

При `Buff.toString()` получаю

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_0 Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

Чо делать, как быть? Замечу, что, если брать часть из буфера, то всё ок. 
Пределы чтоль какие-то есть, где я не дочитал?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А, тьфу. Можно же сразу буфер в файл пихать. Эх блин:

```
fs.write(file_handle, Buff, 0, Buff.length, 0, function() {....
```